# How can I get Windows 7 to synch to chronos.csr.net

Tags: windows, ntp

Moderators: Not strictly a programming question, but of interest to a lot of programmers. And you killed SuperUser!

I can't get Windows 7 to synch to chronos.csr.net.

I keep getting "Timed Out" message.

Anyone know a way round this please?

Comment: Who killed SuperUser??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chronos.csr.net seems to be down, which is probably causing your time-out. You can check it yourself [here](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/chronos.csr.net).

Also tried pinging and connecting to NTP port 123, both resulted in timeouts:

```
C:\Users\ManeatingKoala>ping chronos.csr.net

Pinging chronos.csr.net [194.35.252.7] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 194.35.252.7:
        Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

C:\Users\ManeatingKoala>telnet chronos.csr.net 123
Connecting To chronos.csr.net...Could not open connection to the host, on port 1
23: Connect failed
```

Comment: Ah I see. Do you know of any other Primary ntp serves?

Comment: http://www.pool.ntp.org/zone/@

Comment: Could you accept my answer if it answers your question?